# Convert SQL server query to SQLite

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have the following SQL server query, that I would like to convert into an SQLite query

I am mainly struggling with the aliased left outer join. Any help is much appreciated

```
SELECT t.col1, isnull(b.term_date, t.term_date) as term_date,
  FROM table1 t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN(
       SELECT form_num, max(avg_term_date) term_date
       FROM table2
       GROUP BY form_num
    ) b on b.form_num = t.form_num;
```

Comment: Replace `isnull` with `ifnull` and remove a comma after the alais name of `term_date` in the select clause of table1 and it worked for me in sqlite online compiler

Answer (score 1):

Right the query with `coalesce()` and it looks like standard SQL:

```
select t.col1,
       coalesce(b.term_date, t.term_date) as term_date
from table1 t left outer join
     (select form_num, max(avg_term_date) term_date
      from table2
      group by form_num
     ) b
     on b.form_num = t.form_num;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff sorry but my question is how to translate the left outer join with a select statement.
In SQL server you can do this easily but I am not sure how to do this in SQLite?

Comment: @marou . . . I don't know what you *intended* to ask, but the question is:  "I would like to convert into an SQLite query".  This answers the question that you have asked.  If you have a different question, ask as a *new* question.

Comment: when I try running they query you have given I get the message:
"expected one of the following: ON USING" in my editor because it thinks the SQLite query is missing some extra directives. Thank you.

Comment: @marou . . . Except for a typo in your original query, this works fine in SQLite:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=87e30a5ad9abeb7f83be86f6c860bc89.